# Oracle - Max value from each date with date/time

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have table with column Date with timestamp, value in seconds and have query like

Table

```
2017-01-10 06:45:00 PM  1119
2017-01-10 03:30:00 PM  1054
2017-01-11 11:15:00 PM  379
2017-01-10 06:30:00 PM  377
2017-01-11 09:15:00 PM  375
```

Query

```
SELECT 
  TO_char(DtTm,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss AM') As DataDt,      
  max(MaxSec) as Wait_sec, DtTimeTable.HrID,
FROM DtTimeTable 
WHERE  DtTimeTable.HrName in ('Dept1', 'Dept2', 'Dept3')
AND  DtTm BETWEEN to_date('2017-01-08 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') 
AND to_date('2017-01-10 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')
Group by TO_char(DtTm,'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss AM'),DtTimeTable.HrID 
order by Wait_sec desc
```

This gives me All records and if i add

```
select * from
Query1 --(above)
where rownum <1 order by Wait_sec desc, Datadt desc;
```

I am only getting highest value of result set

How can get DatewithTime, Maxvalue  for each date like

```
2017-01-10 06:45:00 PM  1119
2017-01-11 11:15:00 PM  379
```

Comment: You are showing a table of two columns (without showing their names). But you access four columns (HrName, DtTm, MaxSec and HrID) from it. This makes it hard to understand what your query is doing and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: I take it that the *output* of the query the OP shows in the post should be the *input* to what he's asking for help on. Still, the *output* of that query shows three columns (an ID in addition to the datetime and the value). It's not clear what he wants to do with that ID in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Select *
From (
    Select t.*,
      Row_number() over(partition by trunc(datecol) order by value desc nulls last) rn
    From yourtable t
) where rn = 1;
```

It assign row number within date based on descending order your value column and then filters to get the first row

Comment: @vkp nope. OP want to get the rows with max value.

Comment: @GurV.. Thank a lot.. perfect solution :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution below uses grouping, the `MAX()` aggregate function, and the `FIRST/LAST` function (with `KEEP DENSE_RANK`). If for a date the same highest value is reached more than once, it picks the first time during the day that the value was reached.

```
with
     test_data( dt, val ) as (
       select to_date('2017-01-10 06:45:00 PM', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss AM'), 1119 from dual 
       union all
       select to_date('2017-01-10 03:30:00 PM', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss AM'), 1054 from dual 
       union all
       select to_date('2017-01-11 11:15:00 PM', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss AM'),  379 from dual 
       union all
       select to_date('2017-01-10 06:30:00 PM', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss AM'),  377 from dual 
       union all
       select to_date('2017-01-11 09:15:00 PM', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss AM'),  375 from dual
     )
--  end of test data; SQL query begins below this line (use actual table and column names)
select min(dt) keep(dense_rank last order by val) as dt, max(val) as val
from   test_data
group by trunc(dt)
order by dt   --  if needed
;

DT                            VAL
---------------------- ----------
2017-01-10 06:45:00 PM       1119
2017-01-11 11:15:00 PM        379

2 rows selected.
```